# Term for “extent/proportion of a population [that meet some condition]”

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, mathematics, science, statistics

What is a technical term (perhaps from statistics) for **the extent (or proportion) that a specified condition applies** to some given population?

For example:

- There is a communicable cancer currently ravaging the Tasmanian Devil species. I would use this term to say “the [extent/proportion in the population] of the cancer”.
- Software test suites exercise some amount of the application code, by some metric such as code paths exercised by the tests. I would use this term to say “the [extent/proportion of application tested] of the test suite”.

Note that this is a descriptor for the *condition*, not the population.

Also note this is not a term that applies specially to human populations, but rather to any population of things, living or inert, that could be affected by the condition.

What term, applied to the condition, connotes this meaning of penetration and/or extent?

Comment: There isn't one because metrics just don't work that way. The population is what the metric is being applied to, not the condition. So in any sort of formal situation, you simply have to invert the sentence and focus on the population. You can talk about the prevalence of cancer, but not the prevalence of a test routine.

Comment: Please do not modify the essence of a question. You may post a fresh new question if needed.

Comment: Are you looking for a  term similar to *domain*?

Comment: @kris, the question has not changed essence, rather I have clarified the original meaning of the question. If I ask a new question, I have to hope it won't be marked as a duplicate :-)

Comment: See my most recent comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's called *demographic*, a particular sector of a population.

***[demographic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demographic)***

> noun
>   A particular sector of a population.
>   *‘the drink is popular with a young demographic’
>
>   ‘All of this places me squarely in the demographic of People Who Tend To Buy Things Online.’*

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/demographic):

> **2.** a section of the population sharing common characteristics, such as age, sex, class, etc
>   *This creaky sitcom must have been conceived by executives anxious to appeal to a particular demographic.* Times, Sunday Times (2015)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have added examples to the question to be clear I'm not looking for a modifier of the population, but a modifier of the condition.