# Term for people in the same life situation

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

What is a term for people in the same life situation?

Like, people who have the same health issue, or pregnant women.

Comment: "We are in the same boat" -- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-in-the-same-boat ; https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-the-same-boat.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Isn't there a two-word max term for that though?

Comment: Why the close vote? The Q can stand on its own with what is provided by way of examples.

Comment: Perhaps, but I can't think of any such phrase right now. See also the related post: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/474403/14666

Comment: Maybe ***similarly affected/afflicted/infected***

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean a *cohort*?

cohort *n.* *sing.* or *pl.*

2 • a group of people banded together or treated as a group: a cohort of civil servants patiently drafting legislation.
• a group of people with a common statistical characteristic: the 1940–44 birth cohort of women.