# Term for “extent/proportion [into some population] of the condition”?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, science, statistics

What is a technical term (perhaps from statistics) for **the extent (or proportion) that a specified condition applies** to some given population?

For example:

- There is a communicable cancer currently ravaging the Tasmanian Devil species. I would use this term to say “the [extent/proportion in the population] of the cancer”.
- Software test suites exercise some amount of the application code, by some metric such as code paths exercised by the tests. I would use this term to say “the [extent/proportion of application tested] of the test suite”.

Note that this is a descriptor for the *condition*, not the population. (As [requested on a comment at a similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474403/term-for-extent-proportion-of-a-population-that-meet-some-condition#comment1145773_474403), I am making a new question to be clearer.)

Also note this is not a term that applies specially to human populations, but rather to any population of things, living or inert, that could be affected by the condition.

What term, applied to the condition, connotes this meaning of penetration and/or extent?

Comment: Maybe I need more context, but I actually think "extent" works well as a descriptor of the condition. Or other synonyms like "breadth" or "magnitude".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one I have used repeatedly across many diciplines is

[Scope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/scope)

This encompasses **extent** range sweep spread … etc.

"the extent that lies within the powers of something "

However it is not a perfect fit for your **range** of questions, which suggest you are looking more for a *conditional* associated word **Category, Class, Order, Nature or [Quality](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quality)** which collectively can be referred to as a

[**Property**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/property) which has a secondary use as an attribute common to all members of a class

Comment: Thank you, I think “scope” has the connotations and limits I am needing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **"prevalence"** or **"prevalence rate"** ?

> - "[prevalence](https://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/statistics/what-is-prevalence.shtml) is the proportion of a population who have a specific characteristic in a given time period."

Examples from the web:

[**1**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=LlZRZjX-D_gC&pg=PT21&dq=prevalence&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIyoLwsvPeAhVBHZAKHSTWAYEQ6AEIKDAA) "...higher HIV **prevalence** among youth 15–24 years (10.3% vs. 9.3%) and a similar prevalence in adults 25 years and older (15.6% vs. 15.5%)."

[**2**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=JzLw4_RGv2MC&pg=PA54&dq=prevalence&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0_Yy3s_PeAhUCGJAKHVwQBGw4ChDoAQgnMAA)  "This study investigated the impact of an anti-bullying program on the **prevalence** of bullying at the junior and senior high level."

[**3**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=A0W_BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22the+prevalence+of+crime+in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic9uK1tPPeAhUGGZAKHS8JCBMQ6AEIRzAF) "The Memphis Police Department partnered with IBM to develop a predictive tool to reduce the **prevalence** of crime in the city.7"